# How to install patch in Mafia 1

Tags: mafia-1

I just downloaded mafia 1 city of lost heaven and its a .zip file, and when I extracted the whole thing to my hard drive I could play the game but it was not really 'installed' to my computer(if u know what i mean). So I cannot install any patches to the game. Please help as I want to play this game with the latest patch. I tried moving the 'save game' file to my C drive but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Might help if you told us where you got this .zip file from? If it's a legitimately bought game, the site would have install instructions we could help you with. If it's a cracked game, we do not provide support for that here.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are playing a cracked, no-install version of Mafia. You cannot install patches on such versions, because the patches cannot locate the files.

Since this is obviously not a legit version, I can only give you the legit option of actually buying the game, so that you can install patches.